# Boost Asio io_service, Read Messages from Client

Tags: java, c++, tcp, boost-asio

I am trying to Create a simple Tcp Server in C++ using Boost ASio Library. I wrote two classes TcpConnection and TcpServer.

The behaviour I need is that The Tcp Server should be able to send messages to all the connected clients and clients should be able to register/deregister with the server.

I was able to achieve the message sending from server. I was unsuccessful with the reading from clients part. My client is written in java, using apache mina.

Server Code

```
message = message + "\r\n"; 
const int bytesToSend = message.length(); 
boost::system::error_code error;
boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(message, bytesToSend), boost::asio::transfer_all(), error);
```

Client code

```
ConnectFuture future = ioConnector.connect(new InetSocketAddress(Port),
                new TriggerReceiverHandler();
System.out.println("Message Receiver started and listening on port "+ Port);
IoSession session = future.getSession();
session.write(new String("TEst Message From Client"));
```

On the server the code to read the messages is done using the async_read

```
boost::array<char, 1> buf;
    boost::asio::async_read(socket, boost::asio::buffer(buf),
        boost::bind(&TcpConnection::handleRead, this, buf, boost::asio::placeholders::error));


void TcpConnection::handleRead(boost::array<char, 1> buf, const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    if(!error)
    {
        std::cout << "Message: " << buf.data() << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Error occurred." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

But the handleRead is not getting called when I trigger a message by writing to the session from the client. Please tell me if I am doing anything wrong.

I would appreciate any Help..Please let me know if any further info is needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you write a server and client in both C++ and Java to comapre how they both operate. The Java client and server should be able to talk to each other and the C++ client and server as well.  This way you can diagnose which end is having a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly this appears to be incorrect!

```
boost::array<char, 1> buf;
```

You are declaring an array of size 1! I'd suggest something bigger!

```
boost::array<char, 1500> buf;
```

Aside from the buffer, I can't see anything wrong with your code, just check that you are not interleaving `async_read` calls on the same socket.

Comment: I am not clear on what the "just check that you are not interleaving async_read calls on the same socket." mean. Should I open two sockets one for reading and one for writing? i think thats wrong. can you please elaborate.

Comment: no, it means that you must never call `async_read` on a specific socket until the previous call completes (i.e. the handler is called)

Comment: Ok Got it... One question though... How do i know to read when the client sends a message? Right now I'm just reading periodically and by the time buffer is full and overflowing. Also is it good practice to clear the buffer once read?

Comment: You don't need to, as long as your handle operation can accept a size to indicate how much you've got in the buffer. With `async_read`, you should call `async_read` the moment you connect (to asynchronously wait for data from client - you don't need to poll), and when there is data, asio will call you back. In that handler, setup the next `async_read` - effectively the best way to imagine this is you are telling asio, let me know in the future when there is some data from the socket.

Comment: THanks a lot ! That clears everything.. But my issue is not resolved yet. the Handler is not getting called unless I manually trigger the readMessage() function

Comment: which is why I said, in your handler you need to queue up the next `async_read`, i.e. call `readMessage()` if this is what calls `async_read`